# MUI Treeview/TreeItem OnClick Not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, onclick, treeview

So I have a MUI TreeView populated with TreeItems. I need to perform certain actions on click of the treeitems. However, the onclicks are not getting recognized. Could someone please help me with this?

This is my what is supposed to happen onClick:

```
const handleClick = (item, subItem = "") => {
    console.log("here: ", item, subItem);
    setImages([]);
    setTitle(subItem !== "" ? item + " " + subItem : item);
    setBreed(item);
    setSubBreed(subItem);
  };
```

This is my TreeView component:

```
<TreeView
            aria-label="rich object"
            defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
            // defaultExpanded={<PetsIcon />}
            defaultEndIcon={<PetsIcon />}
            defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
            sx={{ flexGrow: 1, maxWidth: 400, overflowY: "auto" }}
          >
            {Object.keys(data).map((item) =>
              data[item].length === 0 ? (
                <TreeItem
                  nodeId={item}
                  label={item}
                  onClick={console.log("dddddd")}
                  // onClick={handleClick(item)}
                />
              ) : (
                <TreeItem nodeId={item} label={item}>
                  {data[item].map((subitem) => (
                    <TreeItem
                      nodeId={subitem}
                      label={subitem}
                      onClick={console.log("ffffff")}
                      // onClick={handleClick(item, subitem)}
                    />
                  ))}
                </TreeItem>
```

Data is a dictionary of key(string) and value(array of strings).

Comment: `onClick={() => console.log("dddddd")}`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/19953
following this thread you can see that there are different solutions to this problem, maybe in your case the last one is the best one.

```
<TreeItem label={<div onClick={event => event.stopPropagation()}>{label}</div>} />
```

and if you want to add an onclick on your label you can add something like that:

```
<TreeItem 
  label={
    <div onClick={event => event.stopPropagation()}>
     <div onClick={handleClick}>text</div>
    </div>
  }
 />
```